# Is there a limit to the number of fields that can be included in a profile?

Tags: profile

The organisation I work with is successfully using CiviCRM (with Joomla) for online event registration. However it seems as if there is a limit of 20 fields in the regaistration profile we use.

Twenty fields are easily used with name, address sex, dietary needs and other questions. Has anyone else hit a field limit and how did you overcome it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not run into a limit of 20 that I can remember you can add additional profiles to a registration page. This could be a workaround for you. I generally will use additional profiles to group fields under profile titles (i.e. special requests & Special needs).

Hope this helps.